# Tiimestamp conversion to dataframe with dates

Tags: python, dataframe, timestamp

I'm a new python user with Jupiter notebooks.

I have that :

```
[Timestamp('2022-01-14 00:00:00', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2022-02-12 00:00:00', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2022-02-13 00:00:00', freq='D')]
```

And I would like to have a dataframe with only date XXXX-XX-XX with this type : datetime64[ns] to use with plotly.

Could you tell me how to do that ?
Thank you

Comment: What is the source of the data?  Python timestamps do not have a freq component, so I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Hi and thank you for you reply. The original dataframe is get using this code :   

`endpoint = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday'  
res = requests.get(endpoint + '?fsym=BTC&tsym=EUR&limit=2000')  
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(res.content)['Data'])  
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')`  

 After that, the timestamp "[Timestamp('2022-01-14 00:00:00', freq='D')... " come from this code :  
`last_date = df['time'].values[-1]  
prediction_dates = pd.date_range(last_date, periods=num_prediction+1).tolist() `